# UNNotificationServiceExtension didRecieve not being run, cannot see image thumbnail

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Within my app, I can't seem to get my messages with images to come through. It used to work before, I'm still on the HTTP protocol but not being able to hit didRecieve in the background, kinda been searching up and down stackoverflow but I feel there are slightly different answers to each one.

This is my App delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: application)
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = MoonTabs()

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(r: 198, g: 214, b: 91)
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.moonNavy
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.moonNavy
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.init(r: 198, g: 214, b: 91)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([
            NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue: UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 20)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.init(r: 198, g: 214, b: 91)])

        
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Registered for notifications", deviceToken)
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Registed with token", fcmToken as Any)
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        //print("Notification info \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        if let fromUserName:String = notification.request.content.userInfo["fromUserId"] as? String {
            if ( fromUserName != ChatLogController.CURRENT_CHAT_UNAME) {
                completionHandler(.banner)
            }
        } else {
            completionHandler(.banner)
        }
        
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(response)
        if let notifType:String = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["type"] as? String {
            if ( notifType == "MESSAGE") {
                print(response)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MoonTabs.showMessagesTabNotify, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        print("Attempting to register for notifications")
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        //user notification auth
        
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to request authK", err)
                return
            }
            if granted {
                print("Auth granted.")
            } else {
                print("Auth denied.")
            }
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        NotificationUtils().clearDailyOpenNotifications()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}


// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(_ input: [String: Any]?) -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? {
    guard let input = input else { return nil }
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map { key, value in (NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: key), value)})
}
```

This is my Notification extension:

```
import UserNotifications
import UIKit

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    static var CURRENT_CHAT_UNAME:String = ""
    
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            
            // Skip Nitification display if inside the users chat
            if let fromUserName:String = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["fromUserId"] as? String {
                if ( fromUserName == NotificationService.CURRENT_CHAT_UNAME) {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            
            // Below process saves the notification attachment to local through url and attach image to notification
            // 1
            guard let imageURLString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["image"] as? String else {
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                return
            }
            
            // 2
            getMediaAttachment(for: imageURLString) { [weak self] image in
                // 3
                guard
                    let self = self,
                    let image = image,
                    let fileURL = self.saveImageAttachment(
                        image: image,
                        forIdentifier: "attachment.png")
                else {
                    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                    return
                }
                
                // 4
                let imageAttachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(
                    identifier: "image",
                    url: fileURL,
                    options: nil)
                
                // 5
                if let imageAttachment = imageAttachment {
                    bestAttemptContent.attachments = [imageAttachment]
                }
                
                // 6
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
    
    private func saveImageAttachment(
        image: UIImage,
        forIdentifier identifier: String
    ) -> URL? {
        // 1
        let tempDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        // 2
        let directoryPath = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(
            ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString,
            isDirectory: true)
        
        do {
            // 3
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
                at: directoryPath,
                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                attributes: nil)
            
            // 4
            let fileURL = directoryPath.appendingPathComponent(identifier)
            
            // 5
            guard let imageData = image.pngData() else {
                return nil
            }
            
            // 6
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
            return fileURL
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    private func getMediaAttachment(
        for urlString: String,
        completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void
    ) {
        // 1
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        // 2
        ImageDownloader.shared.downloadImage(forURL: url) { result in
            // 3
            guard let image = try? result.get() else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            // 4
            completion(image)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the payload that I am sending:

```
function sendNotification(topic, title, bodyText) {
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: bodyText,
      badge: '1'
    },
    data: {
      type: 'MESSAGE',
      fromUserId: title
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
}

function sendNotificationWithAttachment(topic, title, bodyText, imageUrl) {
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: bodyText,
      badge: '1',
      mutable_content: 'true',

    },
    data: {
      type: 'MESSAGE',
      fromUserId: title,
      attachmentUrl: imageUrl
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
}
```

Please tell me if there's anything immediately obvious to why this is not working. My notifications are still being called, I just don't have the image data within them anymore, the didRecieve never fires, I understand its in an extension and you have to attach it but I've not had any luck with that either.